# How to check for unique values in two columns with one query?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL table where two of the fields are supposed to be unique.  As new data is offered up I need to check if it already exists, and so would like to do something like (PDO parameters included):

```
SELECT COUNT(foo),COUNT(bar) 
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE foo=:foo 
OR bar=:bar;
```

The problem here is that if both values will come back with identical counts, so in the event of that count being 1 I don't know which column contains the matching value.  Obviously I could split this into 2 queries, but is there a neater way to check both at once?

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is XOR? I didn't understand your question that well. "...is that if both values will come back with identical counts."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN foo='foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FooCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bar='bar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BarCount
FROM
    `mytable`
```

Comment: Didn't you forget the `where` clause?

Comment: You do not need the where statement because of the `case`.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you could fake it like:

```
SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM `mytable` WHERE foo=:foo
UNION
SELECT COUNT(bar) FROM `mytable` WHERE bar=:bar;
```

or

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM `mytable` WHERE foo=:foo) AS `foo`, (SELECT COUNT(bar) FROM `mytable` WHERE bar=:bar) AS `bar`;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(IF(foo=:foo, 1, 0)) as foo, SUM(IF(bar=:bar, 1, 0)) as bar FROM `mytable`
```

Between the three, you'll want to test to see which performs best.